# Show URL (PDF) in webview - Android

Tags: android, webview, appcelerator

i need to show a pdf file located in a URL
My code is easy...

```
    var link_condiciones;
var idioma = Left( Titanium.Locale.getCurrentLanguage().toLowerCase(),2 );
if( idioma == "es" ) {
  link_condiciones = "http://micoachingapp.net/webpanel/archivos/viewTermsES.html";
}
else{
  link_condiciones = "http://micoachingapp.net/webpanel/archivos/viewTermsEN.html";
}
Ti.API.info("*** Link: " + link_condiciones );
// Creamos la ventana
var winCondiciones = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        backgroundColor: clr_aux4,
        extendEdges:[Ti.UI.EXTEND_EDGE_TOP],
        barColor: clr_primario_fuerte,
        tintColor: clr_primario_suave,
        title: " ",
   titleControl: Ti.UI.createImageView({ image: 'images/tituloSuperior.png' }),
        rightNavButton: Ti.UI.createImageView({ image: 'images/dummy.png', width: 35, height: 35, borderRadius: 5 })
});
// Construimos el visor Web
var WebView = Ti.UI.createWebView({
    top: '30dp',
    width: Ti.UI.FILL,
    height: Ti.UI.FILL,
    url: link_condiciones
})
winCondiciones.add(WebView);
var btnAceptar = Ti.UI.createButton({
   title: L("txt_acepto_terminos"),
   borderRadius: radioArcoBoton,
   backgroundColor: color_on,
   color: 'white',
   height: '7%',
   bottom: 3,
   width: '95%'
})
btnAceptar.addEventListener("click", function(){
   RegistrarFecha( fecha, navWindow, winCondiciones, winAnt1, winAnt2 );
});
winCondiciones.add(btnAceptar);         
// Mostramos la ventana
if(IsAndroid()) {
   winCondiciones.open();
}
else {
   navWindow.openWindow(winCondiciones);       
    }
```

But i cant see the PDF, only a lote of erros in the console.

```
[INFO] :   TiUIWebView: (main) [2621,15443] Detected com.htc.software.Sense feature com.htc.software.Sense7.0
[INFO] :   WebViewFactory: Loading com.google.android.webview version     51.0.2704.81 (code 270408100)
[INFO] :   cr_LibraryLoader: Time to load native libraries: 2 ms (timestamps     7860-7862)
[INFO] :   cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number     "51.0.2704.81", actual native library version number "51.0.2704.81"
[INFO] :   cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number     "51.0.2704.81", actual native library version number "51.0.2704.81"
[INFO] :   chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(143)] Chromium logging     enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
[INFO] :   cr_BrowserStartup: Initializing chromium process,     singleProcess=true
[ERROR] :  ApkAssets: Error while loading asset assets/natives_blob_64.bin: 
...

[INFO] :   *** Lenguaje: es
[INFO] :   *** Valor   : 2016-08-12 18:00:00
[INFO] :   *** Link:     http://micoachingapp.net/webpanel/archivos/viewTermsES.html
[INFO] :   TiUIWebView: (main) [48206,288996] Detected com.htc.software.Sense     feature com.htc.software.Sense7.0
[WARN] :   cr_AwContents: onDetachedFromWindow called when already detached.     Ignoring
[INFO] :   cr_Ime: ImeThread is not enabled.
[ERROR] :  SensorManager: uid = 10142
[INFO] :   SensorManager: registerListenerImpl: listener =     android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@31ca6080, sensor = {Sensor name="BMA255 3-axis Accelerometer", vendor="Bosch", version=1, type=1, maxRange=39.24, resolution=0.15328126, power=0.2, minDelay=10000}, delay = 200000,  handler = null
[WARN] :   cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a     connection for the pid: 21108
[WARN] :   cr_BindingManager: Cannot call determinedVisibility() - never saw a     connection for the pid: 21108
```

that's the ful code with the problem.
Its only a window, with a pdf and a button.

Appelerador, SDK 5.3.1 GA
Android 5

Answer (score 3):

you can try this.

```
    webview.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);
```

Answer (score 1):

WebViews can't display pdfs natively.  You can try loading the url through a web based pdf reader like google docs, but you can't just display a pdf in a webview.  I'm not sure why you thought you could, a WebView displays web pages, not pdfs.

Comment: Well, this is something i do since long time ago... i'm gonna do what you suggest.

Comment: does not work !!  My link is: http://micoachingapp.net/webpanel/archivos/viewTermsES.html

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your url is this:

**http://www.appcelerator.com/wp-content/uploads/GettingStartedTitanium_Windows.pdf**

1 - Either open the link in external browser:

```
Ti.Platform.openURL('http://www.appcelerator.com/wp-content/uploads/GettingStartedTitanium_Windows.pdf');
```

2 - Assuming that your URL directly displays the pdf file as above url, you can get the binary data using [**Ti.Network.HTTPClient**](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient-property-responseData) and then you can display it in webview like this:

```
var url = "http://www.appcelerator.com/wp-content/uploads/GettingStartedTitanium_Windows.pdf";

 var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
     // function called when the response data is available
     onload : function(e) {
          var pdfData = this.responseData;    // it contains the pdf blob data 

           // Construimos el visor Web
          var WebView = Ti.UI.createWebView({
             top: '30dp',
             width: Ti.UI.FILL,
             height: Ti.UI.FILL,
             data : pdfData     // instead of url, use pdfData blob object
          });

          winCondiciones.add(WebView);
     },

     onerror : function(e) {
         Ti.API.error(e.error);
         alert('error');
     }
 });

 client.open("GET", url);

 client.send();
```

3 - Try this also as I was also stuck in some weird issue once and after finding no help, it worked finally by adding **borderRadius** attribute:

```
// Construimos el visor Web
var WebView = Ti.UI.createWebView({
    top: '30dp',
    width: Ti.UI.FILL,
    height: Ti.UI.FILL,
    borderRadius : 2,
    url: link_condiciones
});
winCondiciones.add(WebView);
```

If it doesn't work out for you, then you probably try to look out some module to display remote pdf file. Good Luck!!!

Comment: Please try this code:

// Construimos el visor Web
**var WebView = Ti.UI.createWebView({
    top: '30dp',
    width: Ti.UI.FILL,
    height: Ti.UI.FILL,
    borderRadius : 2,
    url: link_condiciones,
});
winCondiciones.add(WebView);**

Comment: Well the problem is not any above, but it is rather something I faced first time. Please see my new answer.

Answer (score 1):

As I tried to run the code, the issue you are facing can be solved by putting complete url of what you provided in one of your comment.

Put this : 
**http://micoachingapp.net/webpanel/archivos/viewTermsES.html**
instead of **micoachingapp.net/webpanel/archivos/viewTermsES.html**

Now, what I saw weird is that if I open up this url **http://www.micoachingapp.net/webpanel/archivos/viewTermsES.html**, I wonder why it takes me to some other pdf by simply adding ***www*** in it.

Carefully look at the all URLs I mentioned above, here are these:

1. Yours - **micoachingapp.net/webpanel/archivos/viewTermsES.html**
2. If you paste your URL in any browser and then you will copy it again from the address bar, you will get this: **http://micoachingapp.net/webpanel/archivos/viewTermsES.html**
3. Now add **www** - http://www.micoachingapp.net/webpanel/archivos/viewTermsES.html

***In WebView***

- URL 1 shows the error you mentioned in your question.
- URL 2 is the actual url as displayed by chrome or safari or any desktop browser.
- URL 3 takes to some other pdf...How is that possible???

So your solution lies within these 3 URLs, maybe it is a domain issue or don't know what it is as I never faced such issue.

But for sure, it will work if you open it in external device browser using Ti.Platform.openURL

Comment: hi Prashant, the correct link is: [link](http://micoachingapp.net/webpanel/archivos/viewTermsES.html) i am adding the www and i get the same pdf, i really dont know whats happening with that, i will paste all the error in the question..

Comment: I modified my question with the complete code and the console output.

Comment: Yes, I already found out the actual link you just provided. But it seems something really wrong with the URL...why is there not any www in that url?????

Comment: And if we add **www** in your URL, then it opens some other PDF, how come is that man???

Comment: with "http://www" and without "www", the result is the same... the full console output: [link](https://justpaste.it/wmzg)

Comment: No, I am saying that with **www** we get a different pdf, and without **www** we get some other pdf. Try to test these 2 cases in desktop browser.